# Does אנא ever connote thanking?

Tags: tefilla, language

Does anyone know of an instance where אנא is interpreted as thanking as opposed to a plea or request?

Comment: Why do you suspect such an instance ought exist?

Comment: @TorahKnowledgeSeeker whilst I did not downvote, it could be that since the question does not have much in the way of context or details, it means it is harder to answer. I can only assume that the downvote was not meant to be vindictive. I apologise for you being upset by it..

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there exists that denotation of אנא. In all twelve places in Tanach it means pleading and requesting. See [here](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%90&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh&tvar=1&tsort=chronological&svar=1&ssort=relevance).